# Input Type Date's Content Only Showing 1st Half

Tags: html, css, input, datepicker

Can anyone help me why my input type date field's content is only showing half of its content? There is no styling on this input? Does anyone know what is causing this behavior?

[image: m]

Comment: Please instead of a picture, provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: size of input can depends of parent flex rules. check it